# Selecting large amount of rows from database table with MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a table with attributes like this:

```
likes(id, message, ip, time)
```

`id` is the primary key and is auto-incrementing. Whet I want to do is select 30 rows from this table based on an id that I provide.

I can build a random array of all IDs I want to grab from the table, now I just need to go about doing that. My usual SQL query would be:

```
SELECT message
FROM `likes`
WHERE id=$id
LIMIT 1
```

But I need to select 30 rows. There are two ways I can do this, I can either use a FOR loop with 30 queries, or combine it all into one query and grab them all at the same time. Obviously I would like to do the latter.

Can anyone help me out on the SQL query to use to grab more than one row from my database table at once? And perhaps an example of how I would parse these into an array for easy retrieval?

Greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm confused - 30 rows limited by what? It can't be limited by `id=$id` because then you'd get 30 of the same row. Unless that's what you want?

Comment: Nah, I have all the IDs of the rows I want in an array. I want to go through all of these IDs in that array and get the `message` attribute from that row. The example I used was my example of getting ONE row from the table :)

Answer (score 8):

You could use the  [IN operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp), so it would be something like this:

```
SELECT message FROM likes WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); //or however many
$query = "SELECT * FROM `likes` WHERE `id` IN (".implode(', ', $ids).")";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$results = array();
while($tmp = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
     $results[$tmp['id'] = $tmp;
}
```

Will give you an array, $results, sorted by key ['id'], with each being an array on each answer key-- 'id', 'message', 'ip', 'time'.  So for example:

```
for($results as $key => $val) {
    echo "${val['ip']} posted {$var['message']} on {$val['time']} <br/>";
}
```

Comment: In PHP you create an array with `$ids = array(1,2,3,...);`.